# How to make an increment/decrement input inside dropdown?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So my goal  is to make an dropdown with decrement/increment button like below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTC9Z.jpg

and these are my current codes

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="btn border-0 dropdown-toggle form-control" type="button"
  id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> 
    Dropdown</button>
 <div class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 250px; background-color: #343a40" 
  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
   <div class="dropdown-item">
     <div class="row text-white">
      <div class="col-md">
       <i class="fa fa-user mr-2"></i>Adult</div>
      <div class="col-md text-center">
       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success mx-2">+</button>
       <span>1</span>
       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success mx-2">+</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

So i've managed to make till this point, but i have problems when the button is clicked inside the dropdown, it scrolls to page the top and i also don't like the background color changes when the dropdown item is hovered.
please help me to make it happen, thank you

UPDATE:
so all left is preventing the page to scroll when the button inside dropdown is clicked, can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to keep on dropdown when user click anything in it.
JS:

```
  $('.keep-open').on({
    "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { $(this).attr('closable', false); },
    "click":             function() { },
    "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { return $(this).attr('closable') == 'true'; }
});

$('.keep-open #dLabel').on({
  "click": function() {
    $(this).parent().attr('closable', true );
  }
})
```

html:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" style="width: 250px; background-color: #343a40" >
     <div style="display: block;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px">
      <div style="display: inline-block;color:white">
       <i class="fa fa-user mr-2" style="margin:15px;"></i>Adult</div>

       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success mx-2">-</button>
       <span>1</span>
       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success mx-2">+</button>
       </div>
          <div style="display: block;text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;">
       <div style="display: inline-block;color:white;">
       <i class="fa fa-user mr-2" style="color:white;margin:15px;"></i>Child</div>

       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success mx-2">-</button>
       <span>1</span>
       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success mx-2">+</button>
      </div>
      </div>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/s4nmZVXpLMzZLDSzVd24?p=preview

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solutions! it worked so far, but only one problem left, when i clid the button inside the dropdown it scrolls the page to the top, do you know how to fix it?